# Text on footer Bar

Tags: css, html

My website URL is http://www.hentaireader.com

At the bottom right corner, I wish to put a small link on the red footer bar.

I have created a simple image of what I wish to do.

[image: http://i53.tinypic.com/2lu2o1l.jpg]

How can I achieve this??

Comment: Some existing code could probably help here. This isn't "rent-a-programmer". We can help with your code, not write code for you.

Comment: How do you expect us to answer your question, all I see in the picture? Please place some codes related to your footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code on this page is a disaster. With that said you would have to remove the http://www.hentaireader.com/images/bar.gif image from the HTML and use CSS to create a background-image.

Something similar to this would be required...

CSS:

```
#footer-bar {
      width:100%;
      background-color:#f40000;
      background-image: url(http://www.hentaireader.com/images/bar.gif);
      background-position:top center;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      text-align: right;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#footer-bar ul {
        width: 950px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
}
#footer-bar li {
        display: inline;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin-left: 6px;
}
#footer-bar li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  All characters on hentaireader.com are purely fictional and 18+ years of age.
</div><!--- FOOTER --->
```

Look here... http://jsfiddle.net/b8Xh7/1/

Answer (score -1):

Ok, well first of all. Do you see the red bar? You have a div inside of the div you have an image. You should have put the (red bar) image as a background, and put a link inside the div. Then you could haver positioned the link where you wanted it with padding/margin.

```
#footer a {}

<a href="">Example</a>
```

Comment: Please don't 'position' it with margin/padding. We have `position`, or it can even be done with `float`.